# Android device or resource busy - honeycomb

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

On the 3.0 honeycomb, I am getting this error when trying to access a file. It does not happen all the time. What causes is that I browse around the market a bit and then I come back to my app. It tries to access a file, and i get this error:

```
Exception caught in com.app.android.activities.Preview$DLTask: /mnt/sdcard/tmp/1304702202502.jpg (Device or resource busy)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/tmp/1304702202502.jpg (Device or resource busy)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(Native Method)
at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedFileSystem.open(BlockGuard.java:239)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:101)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:77)
at com.app.android.activities.Preview$DLTask.doInBackground(Preview.java:200)
at com.app.android.activities.Preview$DLTask.doInBackground(Preview.java:1)
at com.app.android.activities.appAsyncTask$2.call(appAsyncTask.java:176)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:574)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020)
```

To get the same code working again after I restart the device, i.e. power off/on.

The same code works fine on the android version 7, but at times it crashes on v11.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and can't figure it out...did you ever make any progress?

Comment: I did not. No one has replied to the forum as well. [link](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/fc861c409d1edddd/019b97ff9affe212?lnk=gst&q=Device+or+Resource+busy.#019b97ff9affe212)

Comment: Shucks. My only solution thus far is to reinstall the app, but obviously that isn't going to go over well once it eventually gets in the end user's hand :)

Comment: I think that the actual low-level implementation of the "sdcard" may only allow one access at a time (this has come up in the past as an efficiency concern); if that somehow gets "stuck" nothing else could use it.  It might be interesting to see what other processes are running, and ultimately what file handles they have open.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue that came out of nowhere: embedded sdcard answered with "Device or resource busy". Tried pretty much everything. Cold reboot was the only thing that helped.

Comment: I tried several available solutions. This worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

It was a file system lock in my case, unplugging and re-plugging the usb cable helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I figured the issue was with the folder not the file. So as a work around, I just create a new tmp folder within my app folder and try to save the file.